# Is there a way to calculate shipping with Stripe Checkout Session?

Tags: stripe-payments

I know that that has been deprecated in Orders, but I was wondering if they support automatic shipping cost in Stripe Checkout Session.

Comment: No, that's not currently supported. You'd have to collect the shipping address and calculate the cost yourself.

Comment: Is their some sort of API that has a prebuilt shipping address page? If I have to collect the shipping address myself would I have to be concerned with security?

Comment: You can collect the shipping address with Checkout: https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-shipping_address_collection but calculating the shipping cost would be up to you.

Comment: @RodrigoAlvarez Stripe provides a library of prebuilt components for the web, including a new address collection component: https://stripe.com/docs/elements

Comment: @RodrigoAlvarez did you figure this out?

Comment: Sadly not, it was just for a personal project that I abandoned here is a link I found that can get you started, good luck! https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/shipping